# Set relative path of a rdlc file for Report Viewer in code behind file

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc, relative-path

In my application I am using RDLC reporting to generate reports. The folder that contains the Reporting View also contains the RDLC reporting file. I want to set relative path of the RDLC file in the code behind (I dont want to hard code). How do I set the relative path?

Here is the Reporting View Path

```
"D:\TPMS\Main\Source\TestPackManager\ReportingViews\StatusReport.cs"
```

and here is the RDLC file whose path i want to set in the above code behind file

```
"D:\TPMS\Main\Source\TestPackManager\ReportingViews\StatusView.rdlc"
```

Here is the path of the exe which is running

```
"D:\TPMS\Main\Source\TestPackManager\bin\Release\TPMS.exe"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to copy the file to the output directory. Select `StatusView.rdlc` from Solution Explorer, and in Properties pane, set "Copy to Output Directory" as "Copy always".

When the exe is being built this file (as well as its containing folder `ReportingViews`) will be copied to the bin directory, and its relative path will be "ReportingViews\StatusView.rdlc".